# How to change font family on TextInput in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text

All,

We are building a chat app in react native, In the text input, we want to implement text changes just like WhatsApp. How can we achieve using react native

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at this package if it can help you out

https://github.com/Astrocoders/react-native-selectable-text

```
<SelectableText
  menuItems={["Bold", "Copy", "Italic"]}
  /* 
    Called when the user taps in a item of the selection menu:
    - eventType: (string) is the label
    - content: (string) the selected text portion
    - selectionStart: (int) is the start position of the selected text
    - selectionEnd: (int) is the end position of the selected text
   */
  onSelection={({ eventType, content, selectionStart, selectionEnd }) => {}}
  value="I crave star damage"
/>
```